# jQuery post form and callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My goal is to allow for non logged in users to view a page with a bookmark button. When non logged in user clicks on the bookmark button, he should be presented a login form in a modal, submit their credentials and have the bookmark added (same way Yelp does it).

My problem is I can't make the login form post the create bookmark request.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
    $("form#login-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post('/account/authenticate_xhr', $(this).serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
console.log("posted authenticate");

            if (data['user_id']) {
                // log in successful
console.log("logged in!"+data['user_id']);
                if (data['next_action']) {
                    // prepare and post next action
console.log('next action!');
                    var next_action = data['next_action'];
                    var controller = next_action['controller'];
                    var action = next_action['action'];
                    var data = next_action['data'];

                    $j.post('/' + controller + '/' + action, { data: data }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    }, "script");
                }
            };
        }, "script");

console.log('ending');

    });
```

When I run it, ONLY "ending" shows up in the console. I can't execute the code inside the authenticate_xhr post request while it seems the request is executed properly on the back end. But the response authenticate_xhr show me the right JSON object...

What am I missing here?

**UPDATES:**

1. I followed charlietfl suggestion and replaced 'script' with 'json' to call '/account/authenticate_xhr' and now get the first post working fine. I now need to execute my js.erb response...
2. Kept 'script' for the second post request and added escape_javascript in the js.erb view

Comment: Did you check firebug or chrome dev tools to see if the request is being made? Does ` if (data['user_id'])` eval to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `dataType` as `script`...needs to be `json`. Even if request is for jsonp that gets wrapped in a function, you still request `json`

Comment: OK...now you are returning html not json. remove the dataType if it is html....jQuery will default to html type

Comment: if it is script inside html it's still html. What you showed before was html

Comment: with no datatype, jQuery returns an error on the Post request (and on the server side: Started POST "/interests/create_interest" for 127.0.0.1, Processing by InterestsController#create_interest as * / *, Rendered interests/create_interest.js.erb (7.5ms), Completed 200 OK in 20ms )

Comment: ok, for the second post request, I had to keep dataType as 'script'. The problem was in my js.erb partial: I need to escape_javascript in some parts of the rendered code. Thanks!